# Merging two eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, knime

I'm currently learning how to make some plugins for eclipse.

I first developed a plugin for the [KNIME](http://www.knime.org) project . This project contains a plugin.xml and a MANIFEST.MF file:

```
(...)
Bundle-Activator: project1.MyNodePlugin
(...)
```

The second project is a "preferences panel" that was generated with an eclipse wizard. It also contains a MANIFEST.MF & a plugin.xml:

```
(...)
Bundle-Activator: project2.Activator
(...)
```

I want my project project1 (KNIME) to use some data from my preference panel.

How should I merge the two projects (MANIFEST.MF ?) ?

How can I get the preferences of the project2 from the project1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

1. Implement all the classes which you need to manage your preferences (i.e. POJOs to save the values) in project1.
2. Add project1 as dependency to project2.
3. Export the classes in project1.

The last two steps make the classes visible in project2 where you can use them.

Comment: thanks, that was useful. Now, as far as I understand, I don't have to care about the MANIFEST; eclipse will handle it. What if I need to create 'N' plugins all using the same POJOs. Should I create an extra 'void' plugin containing all the common classes ?

Comment: Yes. The MANIFEST contains the information who exports and who imports what. That way, each plug-in can see all the classes it needs.